# Data Type in ser.write() function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, raspberry-pi3

I am quite novice in serial connection of Python, Can somebody help me what is the type data used in "ser.write"and also "ser.read" in Python. I am trying to send some numbers to my motor drivers that obtained in Raspberry Pi. but any format that I enter in ser.write and er,read,give me an error after compile.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The data type is integer.

```
>>>type(ser.write(packed_data))
<type 'int'>
```